# asp.net scriptmanager shows password as text during datatransfer

Tags: asp.net, client, transfer, scriptmanager

I'm currently working on an asp.net application which makes use of a user system 
and I was curious about how data was actually sent towards the server from the client. 
It appears that the information which is being sent can be easily traced because it isn't encrypted into a hashcode or anything. It's plain ordinary text.
 
I've used an application called "SocketSniff" for reading the data.
The data sent back appears to be stored in the scriptmanager using the element ID and its value.

Do you know any way to avoid the scriptmanager from showing element contents?
I'm guessing it has something to do with the ViewState but this didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a security specialist but encrypting sent data and the viewstate are two different things.
When you send data over the internet not only the data from your webform is send but, the entire webform is send back to the server. (not using javascript / AJAX) this is only encrypted if you use a certificate. You can easily buy one and it does not have to be expensive. Please note that when you debug the page in Google Chrome (data will appear not to be encrypted) it gets encrypted in the background when you send it.

The viewstate is used for storing data and preventing page forgery. It’s not 100% bulletproof. But if the page is not very interesting for a hacker (the effort often isn’t worth it) I don’t think your building the webapplication for the FBI, CIA or an International Bank so don’t worry about that. When you alter a page “HTML” and add values to elements that can not have a (specific value). Id’s for example. IIS finds a forgery. IIS send a page with Id 123 and get a forged page back with Id 456 in a specific element. Withoud a vieustate this could lead to a CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update or Delete) operation. Now IIS sees the forgery and gives an error to the user.

Hope it helps.